# GTK 3.16 or up for elementary OS Freya

Tags: themes, gtk

I'm trying to install the paper theme for my elementary OS freya but it says that it needs gtk 3.16, i only have 3.14. How do i upgrade the gtk?

By the way, i've already tried to install it but it seems broken. I think it's because of the gtk. Just a guess though.

Here's the screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't upgrade the gtk version of freya, the granite framework in freya only works with gtk 3.14, so if you upgrade gtk, all the system is going to break very bad :P